# How to get the output of a Executable made in C++ in Rich text Box in C#

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

How to get the output of a Executable made in C++ in Rich text Box in C#?

The question is self explanatory, but just to add on further.

Say for i run a compiled program whose output is:

`Made by C++`

Now i want the output of this program (which is console based) in my Rich text Box in C#.

If the program name is:

`example.exe`

How do i do it?

Comment: Re: "The question is self explanatory"  Not really.

Comment: @John:: Well that still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: In fact it is very confusing. You have an executable which prints out "Made by C++"?!

Comment: @nightcracker:: That was an example but if it still confuses you - tell me how difficult is this to understand: #include<iostream> int main() { std::cout << "Made by C++" <<endl ; return 0;} i want the output in the Rich text box after the written program in compiled in C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you spawn a process you're able to get it's stdout and stderr descriptors.
So use appropriate class to spawn example.exe process and read it's stdout and err.

Use following classes:

```
ProcessStartInfo
Process 

//then Process method would do the trick
proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

**EDIT**
I've found following example on net:

```
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("received output: {0}", args.Data);
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Comment: Btw to clarify, this applies to any process you want to start. It does not depend on the language the sub-program you're running was written in. As said above, you are redirecting the standard out/err from the process.

Comment: What are `sender` and `args`?

Comment: @user667389 sender (type Object) and args (type DataReceivedEventArgs) are used as delegates to event handler